# ROS2 Float32MultiArray error converting from python to c

Tags: python, ros, ros2

I am trying to create a wrapper class for the Float32MultiArray object included in ROS2. The wrapper class is set up to contain 3 values corresponding to x y and z coordinates of an object. Code for the class is included below.

```
   class LocationMsg(Float32MultiArray):
        def __init__(self, x_c, y_c, z):
            super().__init__()
            self.data = [x_c, y_c, z]
```

When I go to launch the ros2 project I get the following error that appears to be saying there is an issue converting the data array contents from python to C. Does anyone have any insight into what this error might be?

```
    python3: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-galactic-std-msgs-2.2.4/obj-aarch64-linux-gnu/rosidl_generator_py/std_msgs/msg/_float32_multi_array_s.c:55: std_msgs__msg__float32_multi_array__convert_from_py: Assertion `strncmp("std_msgs.msg._float32_multi_array.Float32MultiArray", full_classname_dest, 51) == 0' failed.
    Stack trace (most recent call last):
    #31   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x503667, in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #30   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x5935e3, in _PyObject_MakeTpCall
    #29   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x534e87, in
    #28   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x59637f, in _PyObject_Call_Prepend
    #27   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x5960af, in _PyObject_FastCallDict
    #26   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x59684f, in _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    #25   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x4feda3, in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #24   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x48bf8f, in
    #23   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x487b37, in
    #22   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x5002db, in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #21   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x487b37, in
    #20   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x5002db, in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #19   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x487b37, in
    #18   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x5001c7, in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #17   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x592bb7, in PyObject_Call
    #16   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x493e03, in
    #15   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x59684f, in _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    #14   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x4feda3, in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #13   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x59684f, in _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    #12   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x50340f, in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    #11   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x49438b, in
    #10   Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x5935e3, in _PyObject_MakeTpCall
    #9    Object "/usr/bin/python3", at 0x593247, in PyCFunction_Call
    #8    Object "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/_rclpy_pybind11.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so", at 0xffffbbe1ae8f, in
    #7    Object "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/_rclpy_pybind11.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so", at 0xffffbbddc05f, in
    #6    Object "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/_rclpy_pybind11.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so", at 0xffffbbde2983, in
    #5    Object "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/librclpy_common.so", at 0xffffbbd98d3f, in rclpy_convert_from_py
    #4    Object "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/libstd_msgs__python.so", at 0xffffa6dc17c3, in std_msgs__msg__float32_multi_array__convert_from_py
    #3    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffffbcc1e4f3, in __assert_fail
    #2    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffffbcc1e48f, in
    #1    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffffbcc11aab, in abort
    #0    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffffbcc24d78, in gsignal
    Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 9066 1000)
```

Here I have provided the MRE. I am using ROS2 Galactic. Casting x_c, y_c, and z using np.float32() does not work as self.data appears to expect a float type that is casted in the super class.

```
#ROS2 Imports
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from std_msgs.msg import Float32MultiArray

import numpy as np

#Publisher class for 3 tuple of blob X Y Z coordinates
class LocationMsg(Float32MultiArray):
    def __init__(self, x_c, y_c, z):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = [x_c, y_c, z]
        

class TestNode(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('TestNode')

        self.timer_period = 1/12  # frequency to call timer_callback

        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(LocationMsg, "/Location", 10)
        self.timer = self.create_timer(self.timer_period, self.timer_callback)

    def timer_callback(self):
        x_c = 5.0
        y_c = 5.0
        z = 5.0
        msg = LocationMsg(x_c,y_c,z)
        self.LocationPublisher_.publish(msg)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    publisher = TestNode()
    rclpy.spin(publisher)
    publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with converting Python to C, instead your error happens inside some C bindings that Python uses. The error is because you're inheriting off a Float32 array message. To keep things simple, when internal type checks happen an assertion is failed since your message isn't *strictly* a raw `Float32MultiArray` message. What you're passing includes data for the type `LocationMsg`. Regardless, this isn't how you should be handling custom message types. *All* ROS messages should be explicitly defined in a message file. The [official documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/crystal/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html) has the steps you should take. For your example you should simply have a message file containing:

```
float32 x
float32 y
float32 z
```

All of that said, there are also message definitions that already exist for what you appear to be asking. I'd highly suggest using [the interfaces already available](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/geometry_msgs/msg/Point.html) instead of trying to recreate the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for the help! The point message is a good idea, but I have multiple topics that need to use Float32MultiArray so I will have to go about defining in a message file.